# If $u \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ with $u(t) \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ uniformly, is $u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Suppose I have a function $u \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. If I know that for almost all $t$, $\lVert{u(t)}\rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$ for some constant, does it follow that $u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$?

The issue may be the measurability of $u\colon (0,T) \to L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: I do not see your issue. If $u∈ L^2((0,T),L^2(\Omega))$, then it is already measurable in $(0,T)× \Omega$, right?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, but $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$ is a proper subset of $L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$, so that doesn't help I think?

Comment: Oh yes, good point.